# Questions asked by Lord SriRama?

Tags: ramayana

In Ramayanam Lord SriRama asks about river ganga, Siddhaashram,about tathaka rakshas, about sage Vishwamitra etc. as written in BalaKanda, Lord SriRama is an incarnation of Lord MahaVishnu itself so why the god asks when he is the creator?

Comment: Related Question : [Why do an avatar needs to go to Gurukul?](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/3814/467)

Comment: If you play football with a group of children, will you show off your might by winning all games? Or will you adjust and teach them how to play the game? Similarly Sri Rama is the God who dwells in all, He pervades the Universe. When He takes up Human form, it is not to show off His omniscience and omnipotence!! It is to teach humans how to lead their lives!! Thus all that He did, is for us. Though He knew everything, He still asked those questions and conducted Himself in a manner that we can all follow and attain Reunion with Him sir.

Comment: @Sai: Very well explained Sai ji.!

Comment: @Jatin Thank you Jatin ji, I am just simply repeating what I have heard from others, in no way am I to be credited for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is true that Lord Sri Rama is an incarnation of Lord Vishnu but he was born as an ideal human. You have seen in various places of Ramayana that he have never broken any rules of human beings. He was denoted as "**Marayada Purushotam**". That's why he acted as he did not know anything in his childhood.

Comment: Yes Thank you ! I understood now as I further read the Ramayanam